# grep : sort strings CASE INSENSITIVE which end or begin with specific letter

Tags: linux, sorting, terminal, grep, io-redirection

i have a file names.txt, now i want to store all the names that start with D in another file startWithD.txt and store all the names that end with E in another file endsWithE.txt (the search being case-insensitive).

i have tried this

```
grep -i '^D' names.txt >> startsWithD.txt
grep -i 'e$' names.txt >> endsWithE.txt
```

Comment: What does that have to do with sorting? And what happened?

Comment: And it all works fine, right?

Comment: @tink we have to sort and store na...so it has everything to do with sorting

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no every case is not working fine some are working some not

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making a copy of the entire file and fully capitalising before grepping all of that.
maybe try pipelining it as well.

sorry if neither of these work i am not an expert but i beleive these methods should solve your issue.

something like this for the switch to upper case:
https://www.networkworld.com/article/3529409/converting-between-uppercase-and-lowercase-on-the-linux-command-line.html